# Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source

Tags: java, android, package

I want to upload a video using `Retrofit 2-beta`. I get this in LogCat "Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source". I found out that there is no such package as Files in java.nio that I have in my project, but I couldn't find its jar file as well. Do you know how to add it to my project?

Edit: My error is exactly like [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs) unanswered question on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not actually an error and safe to ignore.  From the linked [FAQ](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQs) --

> This isn't a problem and you can ignore the warnings.

Comment: It's really weird. I found that, but I thought perhaps it is the reason my file is not being uploaded.

Comment: I don't think it is the reason, I commented on your other question.